# Execute top-level JavaScript function inside an arrow function

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I'm using Vue 3 and Websockets (for context) and I have this wrapped inside a `<script setup>` tag.

```
function hello() {
  console.log("world")
}

const mapper = () => {
  // self.hello is not a function 
  self['hello']();
}

mapper();
```

How do I execute a function using only strings because I plan on adding more and need  mapper to map them to functions outside of `onmessage`.

I am using TypeScript 4.4 and get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: self.hello is not a function
```

Comment: An *object* is a fine *mapper*…

Comment: How? I am trying to use it as such but not getting anywhere.

Comment: Do you really want to be able to execute *any arbitrary function*? That’s a potential security problem. If you explicitly put the functions this is allowed to call into an object, you have your solution and a more secure implementation.